# Facebook and Instagram Integration Error

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-privacy, instagram-tags

I have an integration error between my facebook and instagram.

Tt is causing me to be locked out of instagram. My facebook and instagram are linked, but the 2FA between them is not correct. My Facebook has the updated 2FA number and email, but my instagram uses the hotmail account i originially signed up with that i no longer have access to.

I've recently been locked out of my account due to 'suspiscious activity' and it requires 2FA on my instagram that i no longer have access to.

Is there any way get my data from facebook to propagate to instagram?